# Regexp match strickly html comment string

Tags: regex, comments, strip

I'am trying to use regexp to strip all html comments from .html file.
As we know html comments format are `<!-- some comments -->`
I've create such regexp

`/<!--.*-->/gs`

It works, but if there is more than one comment block in file, it strips no one to another block, but all from first `<!--` to last `-->`
F.e.

```
some html tags
<!-- some comments 1 -->
some html tags 2
<!-- some comments 2-->
```

It strips entire

```
<!-- some comments 1 -->
some html tags 2
<!-- some comments 2-->
```

I'am code with ActionScript language.
Any advice would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: you need `.+?` for this, not `.*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the question mark to make the asterisk lazy:

```
/<!--.*?-->/gs
```

Comment: Thanks! It works right now! Can you explain please what this question mark do for this regexp?

Comment: The question mark makes the asterisk character [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification).  As in "do as little work as possible before stopping".

Answer (score 6):

use this regex `/<!--.*?-->/gs`

Comment: This won't match multi-lines comments.